# Unable to pickle redis-py instance (_thread.lock)

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Redis's client python implementation from (the de facto standard): https://pypi.org/project/redis/

So I'm defining multiple workers in the background, and each worker has a connection instance created on startup:

```
class Worker(Process):
    _db = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self._db = redis.Redis(host="1.2.3.4", port=1234, db=0)
```

However, whenever I try to start an instance of this worker, I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

So I'm guessing that this implementation uses a lock somewhere. What is the workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have this issue on a Unix-y OS with forking, but it looks like a cheap workaround for Windows would be, to delay the redis instantiation until `run` is called in the new process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import redis

class Worker(Process):
    _db = None
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._db = None
    def run(self):
        self._db = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
        # do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Worker()
    w.start()
    w.join()
```

Comment: I came across this solution yesterday, but I can't find an explanation why is it happening on WinOS?

Comment: @Kristijan It's happening on Windows because Windows doesn't support forking for process creation, only spawn. Therefor your redis instance needs to get pickled and that fails because it contains a threading-lock and these can't be pickled.

Comment: Yes - but why does it work in the run method and not in the constructor? It's a fresh object being created and it's not passed as an argument from the parent in order for it to be pickled?

Comment: @Kristijan `run` gets invoked in the newly created process and not in the parent.

Comment: Ah, It makes sense now :) So the redis connection was being initialized in the parent process. I thought that __init__ is being called in the child. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you have it ;) You can watch this with inserting `print(os.getpid())` in the methods for example and you'll see two different process ids.